# How get trap with indy TidSNMP component

Tags: c++builder, snmp, indy, snmp-trap

I'm using c++builderXE with Indy 10.5.7 and I'm trying to receive trap from another agent snmp.

I have no info describing how to do the program to receive trap.

Below you can find the snippet of code which I'm trying to use now.

The ReceiveTrap() method always return 0, which means non data received.

I tested the PC configuration with another program I made several years ago using spare API and the trap is received so I don't this it should be a configuration problem.

Have you some suggestions of hat I'm wrong in the routine below?

```
void __fastcall TForm1::LabelReceiveTrapClick(TObject * Sender)
{
    static bool status = false;
    int ists;
    String Fun           = "[SimpleReceiveTrap] ";
    TSNMPInfo * infoSnmp = 0;

    try
    {
        status = !status;

        if (status)
        {
            std::auto_ptr< TIdSNMP >clientSnmp(new TIdSNMP(NULL));
            clientSnmp->Community      = "public";
            clientSnmp->ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
            clientSnmp->Binding->Port  = 162;
            while (status)
            {
                Application->ProcessMessages();
                ists = clientSnmp->ReceiveTrap();
                Mylog(L"%s ReceiveTrap status = [%d]", Fun.c_str(), ists);
                if (ists > 0)
                {
                    infoSnmp = clientSnmp->Trap;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception & ex)
    {
        Mylog(L"%s ERROR", Fun.c_str(), ex.Message.c_str());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way to set the listening Port for receiving traps. Reading the `Binding` property allocates and binds a socket to a local IP/Port using the `TIdSNMP::BoundIP` and `TIdSNMP::BoundPort` properties.  You can't change that socket's local `Port` after it has already been bound, so your assignment of the `Binding->Port` property is effectively a no-op.

For that matter, you are trying to manipulate the wrong socket anyway. The `Binding` socket is used for sending queries to the remote SNMP system.  `TIdSNMP` uses a separate socket for receiving traps.  `TIdSNMP` has a separate `TrapPort` property for specifying the listening Port of that socket.  When the `Binding` is accessed, the trap socket is allocated and bound to `Binding->IP` and `TIdSNMP::TrapPort`. The `TrapPort` property defaults to 162.

```
std::auto_ptr< TIdSNMP >clientSnmp(new TIdSNMP(NULL));
clientSnmp->Community = "public";
clientSnmp->ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
clientSnmp->TrapPort = 162; // <--
...
ists = clientSnmp->ReceiveTrap();
```

Looking at Indy's changelog, there have been some trap-related changes to the listening socket since 10.5.7 was released, so you may need to upgrade to a newer Indy version to get bug fixes.  Or you could download the latest version and then just add `IdSNMP.pas` to your project directly, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Using only the Indi component I can't read the trap rev 2c
But I found a solution using TWSocket and TSNMPInfo which seems to works well

Belowe the code I used:

**To get the data I use a TWSocket fro FPiette components suite:**

```
void __fastcall TForm1::LabelStartServerTracSnmpClick(TObject * Sender)
{
    String Fun = "[LabelStartServerTracSnmp] ";
    try
    {
        if (WSocket1->State == wsClosed)
        {
            WSocket1->Proto = "udp";
            WSocket1->Addr  = "0.0.0.0";
            WSocket1->Port  = 162;
            WSocket1->Listen();
        }
        else
        {
            WSocket1->Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception & ex)
    {
        Mylog(L"%s ERROR: [%s]", Fun.c_str(), ex.Message.c_str());
    }
}
```

**To analyze the data received I use the Indy**

```
void __fastcall TForm1::WSocket1DataAvailable(TObject * Sender, WORD ErrCode)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int len, cnt, srcLen;
    TSockAddrIn srcSocket;
    String rcvmsg, remHost, s1, s2, Fun = "[WSocket1DataAvailable] ";
    TIdSNMP * clientSnmp = NULL;
    TSNMPInfo * infoSnmp = NULL;
    try
    {
        srcLen = sizeof(srcSocket);
        len    = WSocket1->ReceiveFrom(buffer, sizeof(buffer), srcSocket, srcLen);
        if (len >= 0)
        {
            buffer[len] = 0;
            rcvmsg      = String(buffer, len);

            __try
            {
                clientSnmp = new TIdSNMP(NULL);
                infoSnmp   = new TSNMPInfo(clientSnmp);
                infoSnmp->DecodeBuf(rcvmsg);
                cnt = infoSnmp->ValueCount;
                if (cnt > 0)
                {
                    // ---------------------------------------------------
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < cnt; ++idx)
                    {
                        s1 = infoSnmp->ValueOID[idx];
                        s2 = infoSnmp->Value[idx];
                        Mylog(L"[%s] Trap : [%s] => [%s]", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str());
                    }
                }
            }
            __finally
            {
                if (infoSnmp)
                {
                    delete infoSnmp;
                    infoSnmp = 0;
                }
                if (clientSnmp)
                {
                    delete clientSnmp;
                    clientSnmp = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception & ex)
    {
        Mylog(L"%s ERROR", Fun.c_str(), ex.Message.c_str());
    }

}
```